# Is it possible to transfer ether to contract A if both my constructor and fallback functions are not of payable type ?

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to transfer ether to contract A if both my constructor and fallback functions are not of payable type ?

Also, I can't introduce any new functions.

```
Contract A {
    A () {
     // some operations
    }

    function () {
        // some operations
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking.

As the contract is presented, not generally permissible since it has no payable functions, but ...

There is an exception case. If another contract selfdestructs and names your contract the beneficiary, then the funds *can't be forcefully rejected*. Therefore one shouldn't proceed on the assumption that payment is impossible.

If your aim is to adapt the contract so it can still accept funds, it's simply a matter of adding a function that's payable, such as

```
function pay() payable {}
```

In case you're wondering, it's very conventional to have non-payable constructors and fallbacks and functions designed specifically for handling transactions that should involve payment.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Rob you have answer what I was exactly looking for . (suicide scenario) thank you !!